With jq Intersection of 2 json objects
I have a first json structure.
All the values are always null.
{
    "A": {
        "A1": {
            "A11": null,
            "A12": null
        }
    },
    "B": {
        "B1": {
            "B12": null
        },
        "B2": null
    },
    "C": {
        "C1": {
            "C11": null,
            "C12": null
        },
        "C2" : {
            "C21": {
                "C211": null
            }
        }
    }
}

In the second json structure, all the values are always strings.
{
    "A": {
        "A1": {
            "A11": "valueA11",
        }
    },
    "B": {
        "B1": {
            "B12": "valueB12",
            "B13": "valueB13"
        },
        "B2": "valueB2"
    },
    "C": "valueC"
}

The result would be :
{
    "A": {
        "A1": {
            "A11": "valueA11",
            "A12": null
        }
    },
    "B": {
        "B1": {
            "B12": "valueB12"
        },
        "B2": "valueB2"
    },
    "C": {
        "C1": {
            "C11": null,
            "C12": null
        },
        "C2" : {
            "C21": {
                "C211": null
            }
        }
    }
}

How do I fill the first json keys with values from the second if the keys exists in the second json, otherwise we keep the null values
I've tried with jq on bash but without success. I'm ready to use whatever tool that makes the job.

Re "How do I fill the first json with values from the second if they exists?": What is they here? The values from the first or the values from the second? Also, do you regard null as an existing value? If not, what about false? This would be instantly clear if you provided the expected output document to your sample inputs. Maybe you are just looking for jq '. * input' first.json second.json

Added some explanation and the result

Iterate with reduce over the paths from paths(. == null), get the corresponding value in the second input using getpath, and set it using setpath or fall back to the current iteration value using ? // ..
jq 'input as $in |
  reduce paths(. == null) as $p (.; setpath($p; $in | getpath($p))? // .)
' first.json second.json

{
  "A": {
    "A1": {
      "A11": "valueA11",
      "A12": null
    }
  },
  "B": {
    "B1": {
      "B12": "valueB12"
    },
    "B2": "valueB2"
  },
  "C": {
    "C1": {
      "C11": null,
      "C12": null
    },
    "C2": {
      "C21": {
        "C211": null
      }
    }
  }
}

Demo

Working like a charm. You saved my day!

Edit: Didn't notice that you've added the constraints to null and strings, which made it much simpler.
